# Am I Burning the Bridges with the Company?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process

Company A booked a hotel one week before the interview for me. However, I recently received an offer from company B and already accepted it.

I heard that people should not continue to interview after accepting an offer, so I send an email to cancel the interview with company A two days before the interview. I didn't realize this might burn the bridges between company A because they already made a reservation for the hotel. I thought reservation for hotel can be canceled when I wrote the email. Now, I am not sure if the reservation is refundable for company A. Am I burning the bridges with company A?

I do feel bad if I unintentionally burned the bridges. Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you ***assuming*** that you "burned bridges"? Did they ***tell you*** as much? It's unclear what you're asking. _**"Am I burning bridges"**_ is inaccurate, as your actions are already in the past. Did you _**burn**_ bridges is an unclear question because you're not telling us how they reacted to you cancelling, and we are not mind readers. Regardless, why do you care? You have a new job, and are presumably happy about it. Move on with your life.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, They did reply saying "thanks for letting them know." I am worry about if I doing something unprofessional. Do I look very bad with the company after doing this?

Comment: @urbanrain How they react will always depend on the company and to a greater extent on how you worded your email. Beyond that, the question of professionally cancelling an interview when there are travel expenses involved [has already been covered here.](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/78899/how-to-politely-cancel-an-interview-if-the-company-has-paid-for-my-travel-expens) Edit: and [there's this question as well](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40985/) that covers whether it's ethical or not.

Comment: Fwiw, any responsible hr department will make sure that things like hotel reservations and flights are refundable. It costs more, but changing plans is common for all business. If they don't do that it really isn't your fault.

Answer (score 13):

**Relax**.

In the grand scheme of things, the cost of a hotel is very minor compared to the cost of finding the right person to hire.

It sounds like you did everything right - you set up an interview with A, got the job with B (you do have a signed offer letter including salary and start dates, right), then contacted A to cancel.

It would have been unprofessional to waste A's time interviewing for a job you knew you weren't going to accept.

It would have been unprofessional (& personally irresponsible) to cancel the interview with A before you were firmly committed to B - if that had happened and the job with B fell through, you might not have either job.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I did electronically signed an offer with salary and start day for company B before I contact company A.

Answer (score 5):

**Breathe. You did nothing wrong.**

Once you knew that you were accepting an offer with Company B and did not plan to consider Company A anymore, you did the right thing by telling them. Companies know that they will not hire everyone who interviews with them, so they view any associated expenses as a sunk cost. Aside from that, the hours of pay that would have been spent on your interview is likely much more than the cost of the hotel, so you probably still saved them money by cancelling.

Regardless of money, as long as you were polite and professional in your communications, you will not* burn any bridges by deciding to go with a different company. This is business, and you have to choose what is best for you. Since you are so concerned with burning bridges, I'm guessing you want to keep Company A as an option should you need future employment. If you do ever reapply with them, you may be asked why you chose Company B over them.

**This assumes the folks at Company A behave professionally themselves.*

Comment: Thank you, it is definitely great to know that I didn't do something unprofessional.